# Drawing lines between elements in WPF

Tags: wpf, drawing, lines

What is a good approach for drawing lines between elements in WPF?

I have a view in my application with several buttons that make up a diagram. They scale and move depending on the view's size and shape. I would like to indicate a relationship between some of the buttons using a line.

I am not using a `Canvas` to lay everything out because I want the buttons' relative positions to be dynamic, and I do not want everything to scale at the same rate (like a `ViewBox` does).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to use a `Grid` with a `Canvas` and my elements in the same cell. I drew the lines in the `Canvas` in my code-behind file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a container Control to be able to define the relationship of the buttons.

Once this is established, drawing the line should be a matter of overriding `OnRender`, finding the position of each child control, and using the `DrawingContext` to draw the line.